# Lightning - An internal error has occured

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am trying to show a list of custom object records via a lightning component

Custom Object : Book__c with two fields

The lightning application comprise of two lightning components one for adding a record and the second one displays all the records from Salesforce

Below is my code

**Application markup**

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds" >
    <c:CreateBookComponent />

    <c:ShowAddedBookComponent />
</aura:application>
```

**Component 1 (enter a new record) markup**

```
<aura:component controller="BookController" >
    <aura:attribute name="book" type="Book__c" default="{'sobjectType':'Book__c','Book_Name__c':'','Book_Author__c':''}"/>

    <div class="slds-card slds-p-top--medium">
        <header class="slds-card__header">
            <h3 class="slds-text-heading--small">Create a New Book</h3>
        </header>


    </div>

    <form class="slds-form--stacked">

    <div class="slds-form-element">
        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
            <ui:inputText aura:id="idBookName" label="Book Name:"  labelClass="slds-form-element_label" value="{!v.book.Book_Name__c}"/>
        </div>
    </div>

        <div class="slds-form-element">
            <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                <ui:inputText aura:id="idBookAuthor" label="Book Author:"  labelClass="slds-form-element_label" value="{!v.book.Book_Author__c}"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="slds-form-element">
            <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                <ui:button label="Add New Book" class="slds-button slds-button--brand" press="{!c.AddNewBookHandler}"/>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
</aura:component>
```

**Component 2 (list of all records) markup**

```
<aura:component controller="BookController" >
    <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit}" value="{!this}"/>

    <aura:attribute name="allbooks" type="Book__c[]"/>    
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.allbooks}" var="each_book">
        <force:outputField aura:id="op_Bookname" value="{!each_book.Book_Name__c}"/>
        <force:outputField aura:id="op_Bookauthor" value="{!each_book.Book_Author__c}"/>
        <br/>
    </aura:iteration>

</aura:component>
```

**Component 1 controller**

```
({
    AddNewBookHandler : function(component, event, helper) {
        var newBook = component.get("v.book");

        if(newBook.Book_Name__c === 'Please enter Book Name' )
        {
            alert("You need to change the details first !!");
        }
        var action=component.get("c.saveBook");
        action.setParams({"b":newBook});
        action.setCallback(this,function(response){
           var state = response.getState();

            if(component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS")
            {
                //alert("Book Saved Successfully");
                alert("Book Id = "+response.getReturnValue());
                component.set("v.book.Book_Name__c",'');
                component.set("v.book.Book_Author__c",'');
                //component.set("v.book.Book_Author__c",'Please enter Book Author');
                //component.set("v.book.Book_Author__c",'Please enter Book Author');
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Book Not Saved Successfully");
                console.log("Response = "+response);
                console.log("Response State ="+response.getState());
                console.log("Response Return Value = "+response.getReturnValue());
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

**Component 2 controller**

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {

        var action = component.get("c.getBooks");

        action.setCallback(this, function(response){

            var state = response.getState();
            if(state === "SUCCESS")
            {
                //alert("here");
                component.set("v.allbooks",response.getReturnValue());
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Error in retrieving book records");
            }
        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

**Shared Apex Controller**

```
public class BookController {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static String saveBook(Book__c b)
    {
        Book__c inputBook = new Book__c();
        inputBook.Book_Author__c = b.Book_Author__c;
        inputBook.Book_Name__c = b.Book_Name__c;
        insert inputBook;
        return inputBook.Id;
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Book__c> getBooks()
    {
        List<Book__c> allBooks = [SELECT ID,Book_Name__c,Book_Author__c FROM Book__c];
        return allBooks;
    }

}
```

**Issues**

a) I could observe performance issue while rendering the output. The first component is getting rendered without any issues while it takes around 1-2 seconds for the second component to render. Is this common ?

b) The second component does not render properly instead it shows the following message list as

[image]

I did some debugging and found that if I use ui:outputText instead of force:outputField I am getting the data as expected.

Can someone let me know what is wrong with my markup ?

Comment: Most likely have to strinify the new book to send it back to apex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

force:outputField works only when you bind with one sObject. It doesn't work with iteration but if you want to do this anyway you can create another component as shown below.

**Single book component**

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="singlebook" type="Book__c"/>    
        <force:outputField aura:id="op_Bookname" value="{!single.Book_Name__c}"/>
        <br/>
</aura:component>
```

Show All Book component

```
<aura:component controller="BookController" >
    <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit}" value="{!this}"/>

    <aura:attribute name="allbooks" type="Book__c[]"/>    
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.allbooks}" var="each_book">

        <c:singlebookcomponent singlebook="{!each_book}"/>
        <br/>
    </aura:iteration>
</aura:component>
```

PS: It will decrease overall performance for sure but putting this solution if you are doing this to learn lightning.

Answer (score 2):

If your only intention is to display the record values in iteration, you could better use **ui:outputText** instead of **force:outputField**.

This could solve your problem. Please note that you cannot give static `aura:id` for elements inside an iteration. So your component becomes as follows :-

```
<aura:component controller="BookController" >
    <aura:attribute name="allbooks" type="Book__c[]"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit}" value="{!this}"/>

    <aura:iteration items="{!v.allbooks}" var="each_book">
        <ui:outputText value="{!each_book.Book_Name__c}"/>
        <ui:outputText value="{!each_book.Book_Author__c}"/>
        <br/>
    </aura:iteration>
</aura:component>
```

And right now displaying multiple records using **force:outputField** is not possible.

You can verify it by changing the apex method to return a single record and avoid iteration in the component.
 Also you have to give default value for the attribute as follows:

**Component 2**

```
<aura:component controller="BookController" >
    <aura:attribute name="allbooks" type="Book__c" default="{'sobjectType': 'Book__c'}"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit}" value="{!this}"/>

    <force:outputField aura:id="op_Bookname" value="{!v.allbooks.Book_Name__c}"/>
    <force:outputField aura:id="op_Bookauthor" value="{!v.allbooks.Book_Author__c}"/>
</aura:component>
```

**Shared Controller**

```
public class BookController {

@AuraEnabled
public static String saveBook(Book__c b)
{
    Book__c inputBook = new Book__c();
    inputBook.Book_Author__c = b.Book_Author__c;
    inputBook.Book_Name__c = b.Book_Name__c;
    insert inputBook;
    return inputBook.Id;
}

@AuraEnabled
public static Book__c getBooks()
{
    Book__c book1 = [SELECT ID,Book_Name__c,Book_Author__c FROM Book__c LIMIT 1];
    return book1;
}
}
```

I hope this would clear your problem.